# how to get duplicate count and the corresponding value postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, having

I have a table called *duptable* and which contains following *data*.

```
mid mgp

1  cat    
1  cat1    
1  cat2    
1  cat3    
1  cat4    
2  rat    
3  bat    
3  bat1    
3  bat2    
3  bat3
```

as you can see in the above table mid 1 repeats 5 times and mid 3 repeats 4 times.How can I get result like below

```
  mid dup_count
    1  5
    3  4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
 mid,
 count(mid) dup_count 
FROM duptable 
GROUP BY mid HAVING count(mid) >1
```